# Having trouble with my code involving rot-13

Tags: c, character, uppercase, lowercase, rot13

I have to write a program that will essentially return a character that is 13 places forward or backward. It only works for characters in the alphabet and if it's lowercase, it stays lowercase and if it's uppercase, it stays uppercase.

```
    char char_rot_13(char c);
```

What I've done so far is I've made two conditional statements, one for lowercase and one for the uppercase characters from a to z. Then I returned, in each one, new_character = c + 13. But when I tried a test case with 'W', the test failed.

```
char char_rot_13(char c)
{
   char new_c;
   if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
   }
   else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
   }
   return new_c;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, however, there's an anomaly : you will return a char which is not a letter in the alphabet. Can you please try testing it with 'z' and see my point

Comment: The computer doesn't know to 'wrap around' when you add a value to `c` that sends it past 'Z'.  `W` + 13 = 'd' in ASCII but what you want is 'J'.  How to get it to wrap around so that the counting starts from 'A' is what you have to figure out.

Comment: @Adeeb: I see what you mean, when I tested it it told me that the expected result was a '?'. So to fix this, how would I exclude those special characters that aren't letters?

Comment: @MattPhillips: I see what you mean, so, to avoid wrapping around, would I have to determine when to subtract 13 places rather than add 13 places to the character?

Comment: Well yes that would do it for this case, since conveniently 26/13 = 2.  For the general case, you need to use `%` (modulus).

Comment: @Karen If we assume that your interest is only the english
alphabet. Looking at this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/)
 we observe that upper case letter are between 65-90 and lower
case 97-122.

A simple solution would be to to add the 13, subtract 65 or 97
depeding on whether it's an lower or upper case letter respectively.
After that, take the 'mod' of the result by 26 and add back 65 or 97, which
ever you subtracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
new_c = c + 13;
```

ROT-13 is **rotation** instead of just **addition**.

For example, `rot13('a')` should be 'a'+13,
but `rot13('W')` should be 'W'-13 instead of 'W'+13.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution consists in translating the letter to a number [0-25] and use the addition and modulo operations. It may help to consult the ascii code but it is possible to do it using the values of 'a' and 'A' directly.

Comment: I can't use the integer values of the characters. :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
char char_rot_13(char c){
   char new_c;
   if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
      if(new_c > 'z')
          new_c -= 26;
   }
   else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
      if(new_c > 'Z')
          new_c -= 26;
   }
   return new_c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I figured it out!